# Can Ubuntu 12.04LTS fit on a normal CD, 700MB, or i do need a DVD?

Tags: 12.04, dvd, iso, cd, lts

i just want to know if the new ubuntu (12.04LTS) can fit perfectly on a normal cd :)

Answer (score 7):

I stopped burning a CD (or DVD) for ISO files about 2 years ago.

A cheap 2GB Flash USB drive is **3-4 times faster** for installs, and can be repeatedly reused (for later releases).

Answer (score 6):

You can install from a normal CD:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop