# Can I install Ubuntu on a 1.87 GB flash drive?

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb

Can I install Ubuntu with a 1.87 GB flash drive, or is that too small?

I'm sick of Windows but only have a 1.87 GB USB stick to install from. No DVDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

You only need 800MBs of space to create a liveCD.

References:
[Can Ubuntu 12.04LTS fit on a normal CD, 700MB, or i do need a DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/125672/44179)

Comment: This needs some clarification - 12.10 Won't fit on a CD, but it *will* fit on his usb stick.

Comment: @fabricator4 I don't think it will fit on anything less than 2GB will it?

Comment: You can still make a LiveUSB on a 1Gb stick - it only needs 800Mb.  I'm guessing that he actually does have 2GB stick - he's giving the free space as reported in some kind of file manager or disk utility.

Comment: @fabricator4  I think its 2GB as well.  I'll update the answer.